# How do I combine boolean with if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am dealing with the question of:

> Create a Java Script control structure using if..else statement. Declare one variable
> and use Boolean condition to determine whether the condition is true or false. If the
> first condition evaluates to true, then the program will run the first block of code.
> Otherwise, it will run the else block. Show your output using the given condition.

```
{

if weather is equal to thunderstorm;

 then display “Stay at home”;

else

 then display “Happy Journey”;

}
```

Is it possible to show the output in html? How can I fix my code to show the output? It is not working currently.

This is my code:

```html
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    boolean thunderstorm = true;
    if (thunderstorm) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Stay at home";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Happy Journey";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working as expected? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: javascript does not declare variables with a type. you need either `var`, `let` or `const` to declare and possibley to initialize.

Comment: @NinaScholz You were faster :D I added basically the same as an answer but I swear I didn't just copy you. Why did you not add as an answer?

Comment: I see sorry I'm new to javascript

Comment: @user17561422 We were all new at some point :)

Comment: there is still another possibility to declare a variable by using a function with parameters. the parameters are declared, even if no value is handed over.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO :)

If you check your developer tools and look at the console, you should see an error like `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",`. In this case that is coming from your usage of "boolean". In JavaScript we don't have to declare variable types like that, instead you would use `const`, `let` or `var` to declare a variable, like on my example below.

```js
const thunderstorm = true;
if (thunderstorm){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Stay at home";
} else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Happy Journey";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

With JavaScript the type of a variable is not as strict as in some other languages. To quote MDN:

> JavaScript is a loosely typed and dynamic language. Variables in JavaScript are not directly associated with any particular value type, and any variable can be assigned (and re-assigned) values of all types

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: oh now I get it thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome @user17561422 :) If you feel like it, accept this answer as the correct one and that tells others in a visual way that your issue was solved (if I remember right, there should be a checkmark close to the up and down arrows next to my answer)